# Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'imageView' is 'weak'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update my App to Xcode 10 (iOS 12) and editor show me a lot of this Warning messages:

**Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'imageView' is 'weak'**

All these warnings (I have many, really, really many) appear with UIImageView outlets.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!

let logo = UIImage(named: "Cartoon.png")

imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
```

Warnings appear in this kind of line:

```
imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Even though it's the default, `@IBOutlets` should not be weak anymore, in general.

Comment: I did not know it. Just yesterday I installed the Xcode 10 and I am updating my Apps. Thank you.

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak` is ok as long as the UIImageView is on storyboard and assuming you are not removing it from super view. But if you are doing this `imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)` then you must remove weak, coz it will gets clear after the scope ends. But why you are creating UIImageView() if you already have @IBOutlet attached to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer.

I just found the answer right now:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cartoon.png")
```

Forget:

```
imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
```

Or even:

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Cartoon.png"))
```

Simply the code above:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cartoon.png")
```

Answer (score 7):

The main reason is that the `imageView` property

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!
```

is `weak` so when you set this

```
imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
```

rhs is not retained by lhs as it's weak hence the `imageView` will be `nil`  ,  if you want to set the image use

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cartoon.png")
```

or

https://medium.com/@gurdeep060289/color-image-new-literals-in-the-cocoa-town-7ef4f2710194

as it doesn't make sense to init an outlet

Comment: This new option of "UIColor Color literal" is interesting, but I am afraid of losing the knowledge of the code existing. If I abandon the use of the RGB values (red: 50/255, etc) ... I do not know.